# CI Migrations Still Not Loading On Controller In Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have been trying all different methods of trying to load my migrations but not working way I would like to be able to load them.

On my controller I have a form validation which enables the user to enter there database information and then sends that information to the appropriate file.

**Problem:**
I am having trouble loading the migrations at the same time on the same controller. Because it seems to load first then the database information, and then the migration will not load in to database because unable to pick name up.

Been working at it for the past couple of days with no luck.

**Controller**

```
public function index() {
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('hostname', 'Hostname', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Database Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|xss_clean');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('database', 'Database', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('driver', 'Database Driver');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('prefix', 'Database Prefix');   

  $this->load->library('form_validation');
  if($this->form_validation->run() == false) {

    $this->load->view('template/step_3', $data);

  } else {

    $data = array();
    $data['hostname']   = $this->input->post('hostname');
    $data['username']   = $this->input->post('username');
    $data['password']   = $this->input->post('password');
    $data['database']   = $this->input->post('database');
    $data['driver'] = $this->input->post('driver');
    $data['prefix']  = $this->input->post('prefix');

    $data  = $this->load->view('template/configuration/database', $data, true);
    write_file(dirname(FCPATH) . '/admin/application/config/database.php', $data, 'r+');
    write_file(dirname(FCPATH) . '/catalog/config/database.php', $data, 'r+');
    write_file(FCPATH . '/application/config/database.php', $data, 'r+');

    $this->load->dbutil();
        if($this->dbutil->database_exists('default', true)) {
            if($this->input->get('username')) {
                $this->load->library('migration');
                $this->migration->current();
                redirect('step_4');
            } else {
                redirect('step_1', 'refresh');
            }
        } else {
            redirect('step_1', 'refresh');
        }               

     }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem I had to make new function with loading the $this->load->database('default', true) remove all the dbutil in input